# How to fetch data and show in Tgrid in delphi

Tags: delphi

I'm working on an application where i want to fetch data from database and show it in `Tgrid.` Since it doesn't have a `DataSource` Property, i can't figure out a way how to add item in Tgrid.

Comment: Firemonkey or VCL? It makes a difference. The VCL does not have a TGrid - it has a TDrawGrid, TStringGrid and TDBGrid. In the TDBGrid, you attach a datasource and it fills itself. In TStringGrid, you have to manually populate the cells yourself. In TDrawGrid, you actually have to handle the drawing of each cell and its contents. With FMX, you use Live Bindings to connect the grid to the data.

Answer (score 1):

Use TDBGrid instead of TGrid. Otherwise you have to insert manually the data from your table into the grid.

Comment: Thats what i wanted to know. How to enter it manually, as i dont want to use TDBGrid

Comment: The answer is that it depends on how you want to present the data, and what features you want for the user. We can't give you decent advice on which control to use without knowledge of your requirements. You'll need to define the problem and requirements more fully.

Comment: What is it about a TDBGrid that makes you want to avoid using it?

Comment: Because i can't find TDBGrid on my RADStudio palette, maybe because i'm on my 30 days trial period.